# How to import package then compile in java in another java program

Tags: java

I use this command  (javac -classpath Janibot.jar Robot.java) using command prompt and it successful. Now I want to execute that commands using another java program. And I already tried to compile dynamically using JavaCompiler class and it is also successful. Now my question is how can I execute this command javac -classpath Janibot.jar Robot.java using the JavaCompiler class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
// Return compilation log!
public String compile(){     
    Process p = null;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac src/Teste.java");
        p.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
    String result = null;

    try{
        result = scanner.useDelimiter("$$").next();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {

    }
    scanner.close();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i know if error occurs in a compilation process?